# Script внутри SCript js

Tags: javascript

Имеется код вместе со строчкой скрипта.
Имеется функция js которая определяет элемент и вставляет после него.
Вида:

```
$(function() {
var test = "
<div id="test"></div>
<script>
// тут код рекламного блока
</script>
";
$("body").after(test);
});
```

Как сделать так что бы внутри переменной test был блок div и код  и что бы он корректно вставлялся?

Comment: а что именно не работает?

Comment: Замените все кавычки на \"

Comment: @Чад, забыл указать какие из :-)

Answer (score 1):

Поправьте экранирование кавычек, разбейте тег  на части.

```js
$( document ).ready(function() {
var test = "<div id=\"test\"></div><sc"+"ript>alert ('hello from reclam');</sc"+"ript>";
$("body").append(test);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: зачем разбивать тег на части?

Comment: Разные браузеры по-разному реагируют на вложенность тега script. Хромоподобные, например, зачастую обламываютя. Им же чихать на то, что он находится внутри строки. Для него он просто внутри головного script. Как следствие, рушится DOM. В целом, что распинаться - уберите разбивку, потестируйте на разных браузерах. Часть будет бажить.

Comment: Пока сработало везде: Chrome, IE, Firefox и даже в сафари

Comment: А как отфильтровать вот этот код?

Comment: <script type="text/javascript">(function() {
      if (window.pluso)if (typeof window.pluso.start == "function") return;
      var d = document, s = d.createElement('script'), g = 'getElementsByTagName';
      s.type = 'text/javascript'; s.charset='UTF-8'; s.async = true;
      s.src = ('https:' == window.location.protocol ? 'https' : 'http')  + '://share.pluso.ru/pluso-like.js';
      var h=d[g]('head')[0] || d[g]('body')[0];
      h.appendChild(s);
      })();</script>